# Nosetests and argparse not allow get arguments from command line

Tags: python, nose

I did write nose test and get weird error message.

```
import argparse
import nose
from nose.tools import istest


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Arguments for running test')
    parser.add_argument('-p1', '--path1', type=str, help='Some help text', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-p2', '--path2', type=str, help='Some help text', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    path1 = args.path1
    path2 = args.path2
    return path1, path2
nose.run()


@istest
def my_test(my_path1=get_args()[0], my_path2=get_args()[0]):
    print my_path1, my_path2
    pass
```

I start test with command `nosetests --tests=my_file -p1 some_arg1 -p2 some_arg2`
But output displays error

```
nosetests: error: no such option: -1
```

How can I get my arguments from command line with nosetest and fix this error?
Thanks in advance.